# process.stdout, tty$WriteStream. This type is incompatible with stream.Writable

Tags: javascript, flowtype

So I'm getting this type error, and it doesn't makes much sense

```
src/bins/assembler.js:19
 19:            compileTo(module, stdout);
                                  ^^^^^^ tty$WriteStream. This type is incompatible with
 11: export function compileTo(repr: ir.Module, target: stream.Writable) {
                                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ stream$Writable. See: src/asm/output.js:11
```

> To clarify `stdout` is `process.stdout`

From what I understand `stdout` is a `stream.Writable`, I checked the [type of `stdout`](https://github.com/facebook/flow/blob/90f8842acdd0c28fc24952a47401537178cc05be/lib/node.js#L1141) in the implementation to be sure, and yeah it is...

```
declare class Process extends events$EventEmitter {
  ...
  stdout : stream$Writable | tty$WriteStream;
  ...
}

declaration var process: Process;
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong... But I'm using the latest version of flow (as of today)

```
$ flow version
> Flow, a static type checker for JavaScript, version 0.25.0
```

---

Like what I'm trying to accomplish is having a function that writes a generic outputs such as a file or in this case `stdout`, and from what I understand `stream.Writable` is that type, and `stdout` subscribes to it's interface according to it's declaration...

Are my assumptions correct, or am I misunderstanding the point of the `|` operator in `stdout`'s definition? Do I have to be more explicative with my type in `compileTo`? Or is there something I've done wrong in setting up `flow`?

This is my first project with flow so I could have missed something glaringly obvious...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As specified by the [`stdout` declaration](https://github.com/facebook/flow/blob/master/lib/node.js#L1483), the type can be either `stream$Writable` or `tty$WriteStream`. Since your `compileTo` function only accepts the declaration `stream.Writable` which is only resolved by `stream$Writable`, you only can pass an argument that matches this type.

If we look closer to the other declaration, the resolution of `tty$WriteStream` can not be assigned to `Stream.Writable`.

```
declare class tty$WriteStream extends net$Socket
declare class net$Socket extends stream$Duplex
declare class stream$Duplex extends stream$Readable
```

To make it work simply add both types as possible argument.

```
function compileTo(repr: ir.Module, target: stream.Writable | tty.WriteStream) {}
```

If you do not want to import also the `tty` module just for the definition, use the global definition of the types.

```
function compileTo(repr: ir.Module, target: stream$Writable | tty$WriteStream) {}
```